# HTML form send empty content to server

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, express

I write a Node project that has one view Page for the user to get informations but HTML form sends empty content, I several times checked with postman and informations saved successfully, I send it with post method:

```
{
"name" : "john" , 
"family" : "swift",
"meliCode" : "12345" }
```

and return it (its mean seaved to db):

```
{
"_id": "5b05bd2309d3c30404ec5b03",
"name": "john",
"meliCode": "12345",
"family": "swift",
"__v": 0
```

}

but when I send information with HTML forms, fields in a table(collection) its null, just return:

```
{
"_id": "5b05bd2309d3c30404ec5b03",
"__v": 0  }
```

```html
<form action="/api" method="post">
  <div class="container">
    <h1>Register</h1>
    <p>Please fill in this form to create an account.</p>
    <hr>

    <label for="name"><b>Name</b></label>
    <input id="name" type="text" placeholder="Enter Name" name="name" required>

    <label for="family"><b>Family</b></label>
    <input id="family" type="text" placeholder="Enter Family" name="family" required>

    <label for="meliCode"><b>MeliCode</b></label>
    <input id="meliCode" type="text" placeholder="Enter Melicode" name="meliCode" required>
    <hr>
    <p>By creating an account you agree to our <a href="#">Terms & Privacy</a>.</p>

    <button type="submit" class="registerbtn">Register</button>
  </div>
</form>
```

and in the server side with '/api' routing(console.log return '{}') :

```js
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();
const user = require('../models/Users');

router.get('/' , function (req , res , next) {
  res.send('get')
});
router.post('/' , function (req , res , next) {
  user.create(req.body).then(function (user) {
    res.send(user);
  }).catch(next);
});

module.exports = router;
```

Comment: I don't see how this could work with Postman. You don't appear to have a body parser middleware configured.

Comment: @Quentin hey body, I cant understand your comment...I edit my post please check again and see are helped you

Comment: is your /action path in the form correct?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It looks like you do not have body-parser set up. You will need to use the body-parser middleware to access the data in the post request body. More info on the middleware available [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/body-parser).

Here is the example provided by the body-parser documentation

```
var express = require('express')
var bodyParser = require('body-parser')

var app = express()

// parse application/x-www-form-urlencoded
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }))

// parse application/json
app.use(bodyParser.json())

app.use(function (req, res) {
  res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'text/plain')
  res.write('you posted:\n')
  res.end(JSON.stringify(req.body, null, 2))
})
```

Comment: special thanks that's work, not same code but the problem was in body -parser and  urlencoded